# How many congressmen have each of the sessions had?

Tags: united-states, congress

Is data available on how many congressmen served in each of the sessions of congress? When did we start having 535?

Comment: Do you want the answers to include representatives from the District of Columbia and Puerto Rico?  These representatives have official status, but cannot vote in full-house votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size of the senate has changed with the number of states included in the union.  The [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_United_States_Congress) congress had 26 senators, the [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2nd_United_States_Congress) had 29 (one seat from Pennsylvania was vacant).  After trawling through those Wikipedia entries (as well as a good one on the [History of the United States House of Representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives#Number_of_Representatives)), I was able to put together the following data:

```
Year        # Sens.   # Reps.   Total
1789        26        65        91
1791        29        69        98
1793        30        105       135
1795        32        105       137
1803        34        141       175
1811        36        141       177
1813        36        182       218
1815        38        183       221
1817        42        185       227
1819        46        187       233
1821        48        213       261
1833        48        240       288
1835        52        242       294
1843        52        223       275
1845        56        225       281
1847        60        227       287
1849        62        227       289
1851        62        233       295
1853        62        234       296
1857        64        237       301
1859        66        237       303
1861        55        178       233
1863        52        183       235
1865        54        191       245
1867        66        193       259
1869        74        243       317
1873        73        293       366
1875        76        293       396
1883        76        325       401
1889        88        330       418
1891        88        333       421
1893        88        357       445
1895        90        357       447
1897        86        357       443
1899        88        357       445
1901        89        386       475
1903        90        386       476
1909        92        386       478
1911        95        391       486
1913        96        435       531
1957        98        435       533
1959        100       436       536
1961        100       437       537
1963        100       435       535
```

I have omitted years where the number of senators / representatives remained unchanged from the previous session.  Some senate seats were left vacant for the entirety of some sessions; if so those seats were not counted (they were counted if they were not vacant at any point during the session).  I did not bother counting any vacancies in the house, instead I relied solely on the numbers reported on the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: In some years, the number of House representatives has been increased slightly to resolve rounding-error (or similar) problems in the Census.

Comment: Note the Civil War decline in the size of the U.S. Senate and House.

Answer (score 3):

As Jeff Lambert noted, the number of seats in both houses have changed over time due to increases and new laws. The wikipedia sources he links are great but I also just wanted to add [this breakdown from the house's actual website](https://history.house.gov/Institution/Party-Divisions/Party-Divisions/) as well as [this one from the senate's](https://www.senate.gov/history/partydiv.htm).

We discovered these sources while building [these interactive seating charts](https://projectseldon.org/explore?year=1961&country=us) because we wanted a way to verify that the politicians we had for a given year/session were the correct number. And, actually we do have data going back 1789 specifically for the US legislature and would love to extend the visualization (and exports) if people are interested!